# Using Http Client for Request which returns jsp page having content type "application/vnd.ms-excel"

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have one request handler which returns jsp page which has content type "application/vnd.ms-excel" id.

I have another controller in which I have called above controller using HttpClient but I am not able to download the file

Code is as follows:

Controller which returns jsp file which has excel as content type

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"InvoiceGeneration/generatePDF"}, method=RequestMethod.GET)
                public String generatePDF(Model model)
                {

                }
```

Controller which calls above controller using Http Client

```
  @RequestMapping(value = {"InvoiceGeneration/generateMonthPDF"}, method=RequestMethod.GET)
                    @ResponseBody
                public  HttpEntity generateMonthPDF(Model model){


                        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet("http://localhost:8080/BillingInvoice/InvoiceGeneration/generatePDF?invoiceNumber=10");
                        getRequest.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
                        getRequest.addHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\""+"kedar.xls"+"\"");

                            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest);

                        return response.getEntity();

                    }
```

How to get response as excel file download???? Thanks in advance

Comment: The web service you're calling generates a PDF? There's no way to magically transform that into an Excel file.  Your question is not at all clear.

Comment: I'm not sure if it matters, but you probably don't want that `@ResponseBody` in `generateMonthPDF`. Also, you seem to add `Content-Type` and `Content-Disposition` to the request, instead of in the response generating the PDF.

Comment: Also, there's no use in returning `HttpEntity` from Apache HTTP Client. You should get hold of the raw byte array (or input stream).

Answer (score 0):

Have to set the following to response

```
         response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
         or 
         response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");

         response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline;filename=" + fileName);
```